# I am getting Error: Cannot find module 'node:fs'

Tags: node.js, npm, nuxt.js

When i try to nuxt build, i am getting this error:

```
\# npm run build

> ...@1.0.0 build /var/www/.../front/preprod/releases/20230329125502/...
> nuxt build

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:613
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'node:fs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:611:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/.../front/preprod/releases/20230329125502/.../node_modules/rc9/dist/index.cjs:3:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:736:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:747:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:568:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ...@1.0.0 build: `nuxt build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ...@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Please, help me i don't know what to do ?

My node version ==> v11.8.0
My npm version ==> 6.9.0

Thank you !

I try to build nuxt application
Exptectation is to run correctly the application
The result is: Error: Cannot find module 'node:fs'

Comment: Your node version is very old, that's why it's not working, please download a new one. You can also try replacing `node:fs` with `fs`

Comment: To explain the "very old" comment: The oldest still supported version of Node is [v14](https://github.com/nodejs/Release), with the current maintenance LTS being v16 (it only gets security updates), and the current normal LTS being v18. Version 11 was never an LTS, but both v10 and v12 hit end of life in 2016, so you *really* want to update your Node version.

Comment: Hello @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thank you for your reply, i have upgraded to node 14 and the same error still happen

Comment: you generally [need to show your code](/help/how-to-ask) if you have questions why it's throwing errors, but in this case: use `require("fs")`, not `require("node:fs")`. The prefixed "node:..." didn't get added until Node 18. If you can, upgrade to that. And if you can't, be mindful that there are a lot of things that Node 14 doesn't support that are used in modern tutorials and mentioned in the up to date Node documentation.